# Need to know the origin of this equation, it's used in algebra riccati equation as a solution for H-infinity

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, reference-request, optimal-control

This equation
$$
R:= D_{1*}^TD_{1*} - \pmatrix{\gamma^2 I_m & 0\\0 & 0}
$$
is used with algebra riccati equation in H-infinity design solution, i need to know how did we get it?
This is the article: Direct Formulae for the $H_\infty$  Sub-Optimal Central Controller

Comment: Please provide some more context. Where did you encounter the equation? What are the matrices $R$ and $D_1$ meant to denote? What is $\gamma$?

Comment: This is the title of the article: Direct Formulae for the H∞  Sub-Optimal Central Controller, by Da-Wei Gu and others.

Comment: The article does not do anything to prove or explain the result, but they point to a source of the theorem, namely [2]: K. Zhou, J. Doyle and K. Glover, *Robust and Optimal Control*. Prentice Hall, 1996.

Comment: indeed, i have this paper [2] they used the same equation without any further information about how they got it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Does paper [2] give a reference? I would assume that if the theorem is given, then **somebody** must have proved it

Comment: actually I've gotten all the references and no one explains the origin of this equation. i really do appreciate your help.

Comment: hinf optimal control is closely related to dissipativity. Maybe the reader by Casten Scherer and Siep Weiland will give insights? https://www.imng.uni-stuttgart.de/mst/files/LectureNotes.pdf sec. 3.3

Comment: i have found some interesting points in this Lecture Notes but still no answer for my question.